Error 401 al intentar logear mediante en dxtrade mediante mql5 MQL5
estoy intentando utilizar dxtrade para trabajar una cuenta de fondeo con bots automatizados pero no consigo pasar las credenciales del servidor.
tengo dos servidores, uno que directamente no me pertime entrar y otro que me deja pero no puedo conseguir la autorizacion, la cuenta esta dentro de rocket21 y lo maximo que consegui es un error: 401 auth error,
codigo:
#include <Generic/HashMap.mqh>

#define BASE_URL "https://embedded.dx-eightcap.com/dxsca-web/"
#define ACCOUNT_FTMO "acc.."
#define PASSWORD_FTMO "pass..."

string token;
datetime timeout;
CHashMap<ulong,ulong> positions;

int OnInit(){
 int response = login();

Print(response);

  return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}
int login(){
  string url = BASE_URL+"login";
  char post[], result[];
  string headers = "Content-Type: application/json\r\nAccept: application/json\r\n";
  string resultHeader;
  
 string json = "{\"username\": \""+ACCOUNT_FTMO+"\", \"domain\": \"default\", \"password\": \""+PASSWORD_FTMO+"\"}";
  StringToCharArray(json,post,0,StringLen(json));
  
  ResetLastError();
  int res = WebRequest("POST",url,headers,5000,post,result,resultHeader);
  if(res == -1){
     Print(__FUNCTION__," > web request failed... code: ",GetLastError());
  }else if(res != 200){
     Print(__FUNCTION__," > server request failed... code: ",res);
     Print(json);
  }else{
     string msg = CharArrayToString(result);
     Print(__FUNCTION__," > server request success... ",msg);
     
     token = getJsonStringValue(msg,"sessionToken");
     timeout = TimeCurrent() + PeriodSeconds(PERIOD_M1)*30;
     Print(__FUNCTION__," > token: ",token,", timeout: ",timeout);
  }
  
  return res;
} ```


¿ Que lenguaje es ese ? Porque esto: char post[], result[]; es completamente ilegal en C++, me extrañaría mucho que el compilador te lo deje pasar.

es mql5, en si un framework de c++ meido falopa
